# How to get the position of a Click?

Tags: c#, click, position, picturebox

I'm currently making a game where the player will click on one of his units (which are pictureboxes) and a circle will become visible with the player's unit in the center. (Circle is also a picturebox) When the player clicks on the picturebox of the circle I need to figure out if the position of the click is inside the radius of the circle. My question is how do I get the position of the click?

Comment: If you're working towards making a game, using the winforms framework is not the best choice. How about starting out with a console based game and working your way up to XNA (Or any other C# game engine).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your click handler, do:

```
MousePosition.X
MousePosition.Y
```

**Example:**

```
// 
// pictureBox1 Init
// 
this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);


private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y));
}
```

Shows: "`X: 537 Y: 946`"

**One more thing:**

The `MouseEventArgs` with coordinates only receives `MouseUp` and `MouseDown`. A `MouseClick` can't receive your coordinates, because a click consists of a `MouseUp` and a `MouseDown`, and both can have different coordinates.

**One more solution (I think this is best):**

```
private int X;
private int Y;

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", X, Y));
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    X = e.X;
    Y = e.Y;
}
```

Comment: Could I get a code type example because I can't get the click to work when I click a picturebox I did a test:                                                                        protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
            if (MousePosition.X > 200) { MessageBox.Show("YESSSSSSS"); }
        }

Comment: The MouseEventArgs with coordinates receive only MouseUp and MouseDown. MouseClick can't recive you cordinates because click consists from MouseUp and MouseDown and it both can have different coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

With [Yahia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055234/5734097)'s answer, I learned that the `EventArgs` can be cast to `MouseEventArgs`.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MouseEventArgs e2 = (MouseEventArgs) e;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", e2.X, e2.Y));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use the `MouseClick` event of the `PictureBox` for this sort of thing...

see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx

Comment: I still don't see how I can get the coordinates of the click

Comment: The `OnMouseClick` receives `MouseEventArgs` as parameter which has `X` and `Y` coordinates... see the links above...

Comment: I just made it on xna instead