# how to draw rectangle by selecting four coordinate points by user in C# windows form and display the coordinate points in text box

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, mouseevent

In my c# windows form application I am trying to draw a rectangle by getting the coordinates from the user through 4 mouse click events in the windows form, one for each point.

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
        g.FillRectangle(brush, this.Bounds);  // redraws background
        g.DrawRectangle(pen,textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text,textBox4.Text);
        pen.Dispose();
        brush.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to get the position of the mouse when you click, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055211/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-click As for drawing the rectangle, look into  this question, perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529567/draw-a-rectangle-using-winforms

Comment: if you get 4 points as input from the user (i assume you would be using the mouse click to capture the co-ordinates) without any validations then its not necessary you would have a rectangle .. you could end up drawing a quadrilateral ...  what is the requirement ? please be more specific ..

Comment: using mouse click i need to select four points on windows form and draw line to points in rectangle form ...

Comment: A rectangle is defined by two not four points. Maybe you want to draw a quadrangle? Will you trust your user to select the points in a meaningful order? For quadrangles collect the four points in a list, add the first one as the fifth point and do a drawlines..

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is drawing in a `Click` handler.  Don't use `CreateGraphics`.  Anything you draw with that is volatile and unlikely to play well.

What you should do is collect the points you want to draw when the `Click` event fires.  Add a handler for the form's `Paint` event and do your drawing there.  The event args will provide a `Graphics` object for you to use.

A separate method for calculating the rectangle might also be useful to keep that work out of the `Paint` handler.