# How to check whether mouse click was in a rectangle in c#?

Tags: c#, click, mouseevent, visio

I have a couple of rectangles drawn on a visio sheet. I am able to get the rectangles coordinates. I would like to track the mouse coordinates and if the mouse click is in one of the rectangles i would like to execute some code.

Is there a basic example on how to check whether the mouse click was in one of the rectangles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055211/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-click

Comment: @Necvetanov thanks! i have a solution now. but dont know in which file i have to place it. I want the mouse click listener listen to all mouse clicks on the screen. I have a Main-file and a Ribbon-file (because i develop an office-add-in). All the work is done over the Ribbon-File though.